# Carrierwave: `eval': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

When trying to configure carrierwave for uploads, I'm getting this error, it says configuration.rb line 73 and the file doesn't even exist? or so i can't find it.

```
/Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:73:in `eval': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
```

carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

    config.storage = :aws
    config.aws_bucket = 'larfs'
    config.aws_acl = :public_read
    config.asset_host = ''
    config.aws_authenticated_url_expiration = 60 * 6 * 24 * 365

    config.aws_credentials = {

        access_key_id: "ABCABC",
        secret_access_key: "ABCABC"

    }

end
```

image_uploader.rb

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

 include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

storage :aws

def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  end

def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you got the information on the configuring carrierwave this way. Carrierwave uses `fog` to communicate to AWS and any other cloud. You need to set the storage to `:fog` not `aws`.

Follow the documentation here and it should be fine: [Using Amazin S3](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/README.md#using-amazon-s3)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this config format.

You need ["carrierwave-aws"](https://github.com/sorentwo/carrierwave-aws) gem

Please confirm whether this line is included in Gemfile

```
gem 'carrierwave-aws'
```